# QML MapViewer, отображение в QQuickWidget

Tags: c++, qt5, qml, xubuntu

Пытаюсь встроить в своё приложение офлайн-карту. QML-ку с офлайн-картой у меня сделать получилось, если запускать её через `QQuickView`. Но мне надо именно встроить карту в Qt приложение. Нашёл подходящий для этого модуль - `QQuickWidget`. Но как только пытаюсь добавить карту как виджет - получаю белый экран.

map.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtLocation 5.9

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.007774, 92.851004)
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[7]
        zoomLevel: 13

        plugin: Plugin {
            name: 'osm';
            PluginParameter {
                name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory'
                value: ':/offline_tiles/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
map = new QQuickWidget();
map->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///map.qml"));
layout->addWidget(map, 2, 1, 1, 3);
```

Получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должен вместо белого квадрата получить это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблема была вовсе не в отображении виджета. Проблема в том, что не была указана ширина и высота. Блок у меня, естетственно, должен быть резиновый - растягиваться под размер родителя. В C++ выглядит так:

```
map->setSource(QUrl("qrc:map.qml"));
map->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
```